# Как можно сделать так, чтоб seekBar не реагировал на нажатия?

Tags: java, android

Использую `seekBar` как индикатор и нужно исключить возможность, чтоб юзер сам мог двигать `thumb`...

строчка `enabled="false"` не помогает...

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте слушатель для `SeekBar`

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

В переопределенном методе

```
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser){
            mSeekBar.setProgress(FRIZED_PROGRESS_VALUE);
        }
    }
```

Где `FRIZED_PROGRESS_VALUE` = вы изменяете программно.
По факту, мы всегда ставим нужный нам прогресс, когда пользователь пытается перетащить бегунок.